# JSON not match with model

Tags: json, backbone.js, model, symfony-2.3

im try render a html table via ajax with Backbone.js.

The Ajax request works fine, returns the JSON data, but appear the json not match with the model.

Im using, Symfony and Serialize Bundle.

This is my Backbone model and collection:

```
var Auditoria = Backbone.Model.extend({
    defaults:{
        id: 'undefined',
        user_id: 'undefined',
        user_str: 'undefined',
        user_agent: 'undefined',
        login_from: 'undefined',
        login_date:  'undefined'
    }
});

var AuditoriaList = Backbone.Collection.extend({
    model: Auditoria,
    url: $("#ajax-call").val()
});

var sesiones = new AuditoriaList();

sesiones.fetch({
    async: false
});
```

The Ajax response (write on Symfony) do:

```
public function getSesionesAction(){
    $em = $this->getDoctrine()->getManager();
    $sesiones_registradas = $em->getRepository('AuditBundle:AuditSession')->findAll();
    $serializer = $this->get('jms_serializer');

    // Prepara la respuesta
    $response = new Response();
    $response->setContent($serializer->serialize($sesiones_registradas,'json'));
    $response->headers->set('Content-Type', 'text/json');

    // Retorna la respuesta
    return $response;
}
```

The JSON data returned is:

> [{"id":4,"user_id":1046,"user_str":"Meyra, Ariel
>   Germ\u00e1n","login_date":"2013-11-11
>   10:24:12","user_agent":"","login_from":""} ... ]

But in the table, print "undefined" in the cells.
Any ideas ?.

**UPDATE**
Thanks for replies. The HTML view is the next:

```
<table id="table-session" class="table table-bordered  table-hover">
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th>#</th>
            <th># Usuario</th>
            <th>Usuario</th>
            <th>Navegador</th>
            <th>Desde</th>
            <th>Fecha</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody id="sessions">

    </tbody> </table>
```

And the render Backnone is:

```
var AuditoriaView = Backbone.View.extend({
        tagName: 'tr',
        initialize: function(){
            // Cada vez que el modelo cambie, vuelve a renderizar
            this.listenTo(this.model, 'change', this.render);
        },
        render: function(){
            this.$el.html("<td>" + this.model.get('id') + "</td>" + "<td>" + this.model.get('user_id') + "</td>"
                + "<td>" + this.model.get('user_str') + "</td>" + "<td>" + this.model.get('user_agent') + "</td>"
                + "<td>" + this.model.get('login_from') + "</td>" + "<td>" + this.model.get('login_date') + "</td>"
            );
            return this;
        }
    });

    // The main view of the application
    var App = Backbone.View.extend({

        // Base the view on an existing element
        el: $('#table-sessions'),

        initialize: function(){

            this.list = $('#sessions');

            this.listenTo(sesiones, 'change', this.render);
            sesiones.each(function(sesion){
                var view = new AuditoriaView({ model: sesion });
                this.list.append(view.render().el);

            }, this);
        },

        render: function(){
            return this;
        }
    });

    new App();
```

Comment: looks like a problem in your view, not in your model, maybe add the code responsible for rendering

Comment: as homtg, the problem is not in that code. [Here](http://jsfiddle.net/Markinhos/tqH72/) is a jsFiddle where you can see that the JSON is correctly parsed.

Answer (score 0):

I suspect that the problem is that you are trying to print the model's attributes before they are fetched from the server. Try this:

```
var App = Backbone.View.extend({

    // Base the view on an existing element
    el: $('#table-sessions'),

    initialize: function(){

        this.list = $('#sessions');
        this.collection = new AuditoriaList
        var that = this;
        this.collection.fetch({
            success: function(collection) {
               collection.each(function(sesion) {
                  var view = new AuditoriaView({ model: sesion });
                  that.list.append(view.render().el);
               });
            }
        });
        this.listenTo(this.collection, 'change', this.render);
    },

    render: function(){
        return this;
    }
});
```